# When $R[t]/f(t) \cong R[[t]]/f(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-group, ring-isomorphism

Let $R$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and $f$ a monic polynomial in $R[t]$, then is well defined $\frac{R[t]}{(f)}$ , $  \frac{R[[t]]}{(f)}$ when are $\cong$ like rings?. It's sufficient that $f$ isn,t invertible?

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb C[t]/(t-1)\simeq\mathbb C$. What can you say about $t-1$ as a power series? And what this implies about the ideal $(t-1)$ in $\mathbb C[[t]]$?

Comment: That it is invertible and so the quotient is trivial

Comment: So, when it's true the isomorphism? If there is an answer. For example if I ask that the costant term is not invertible in $R$?

Comment: I think the OP is refering to something like [Weierstrass preparation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem).

Comment: @WhatsUp Good remark. I suggest the OP to read the single variable case of Weierstrass preparation theorem as it is stated here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250187228

Comment: I don't see... Could you help me?